# Replace matched lines in a file but ignore commented-out lines using Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

How to replace a file in Ruby, but do not touch commented-out lines? To be more specific I want to change variable in configuration file. An example would be:

```
irb(main):014:0> string = "#replaceme\n\t\s\t\s# replaceme\nreplaceme\n"
=> "#replaceme\n\t \t # replaceme\nreplaceme\n"
irb(main):015:0> puts string.gsub(%r{replaceme}, 'replaced')
#replaced
                 # replaced
replaced
=> nil
irb(main):016:0>
```

Desired output:

```
#replaceme
                 # replaceme
replaced
```

Comment: If `string = "cat cat#cat\ncat cat"` and `"cat"` were to be replaced with `"dog"`, would the desired result be "dog dog#cat\ndog dog"`? I'm mainly interested in knowing if there could be more than one replacement per line.

Comment: Based on your examples: `dog dog#cat\ncat cat` and `dog`. So is it possible to do normal replacement, but when # found just ignore that line, but only from where # starts? This would be exactly as Linux command line works. It just execute commands until # is reached. Multiple gsubs are fine if this can help.

Comment: I don't understand why`"cat cat"` following `"\n"` would not be changed to `"dog dog"` since there is no pound sign in that line.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that the last line should be `"dog dog"`. I have marked your answer as correct one. Well done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand the question. To do a find and replace in each line, disregarding text following a pound sign, one could do the following.

```
def replace_em(str, source, replacement)
  str.split(/(\#.*?$)/).
      map { |s| s[0] == '#' ? s : s.gsub(source, replacement) }.
      join
end

str = "It was known that # that dog has fleas, \nbut who'd know that that dog # wouldn't?"
replace_em(str, "that", "the")
  #=> "It was known the # that dog has fleas, \nbut who'd know the the dog # wouldn't?"

str = "#replaceme\n\t\s\t\s# replaceme\nreplaceme\n"
replace_em(str, "replaceme", "replaced")
  #=> "#replaceme\n\t \t # replaceme\nreplaced\n"
```

For the string

```
str = "It was known that # that dog has fleas, \nbut who'd know that that dog # wouldn't?"
source = "that"
replacement = "the"
```

the steps are as follows.

```
a = str.split(/(\#.*?$)/)
  #=> ["It was known that ", "# that dog has fleas, ",
  #    "\nbut who'd know that that dog ", "# wouldn't?"]
```

Note that the body of the regular expression must be put in a capture group in order that the text used to split the string be included as elements in the resulting array. See [String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-split).

```
b = a.map { |s| s[0] == '#' ? s : s.gsub(source, replacement) }
  #=> ["It was known the ", "# that dog has fleas, ",
  #    "\nbut who'd know the the dog ", "# wouldn't?"]
b.join
  #=> "It was known the # that dog has fleas, \nbut who'd know the the dog # wouldn't?"
```

Comment: Worked well. So this mechanism can modify configuration files, but commented-out lines are not touched, because there is no need. This can be used in Chef, Puppet and others as well. For example Chef doesn't supply this by default and built in FileEdit has some multibyte issues so this solution is universal answer in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
puts string.gsub(%r{^replaceme}, 'replaced')
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Actually, I need very high quality replacement that works in 100% cases. So even line `"    something_here replaceme # comment"` should be replaced to `"    something_here replaced # comment"` as an example